# how to get default value from dropdown list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, reactjs

I need the default value of dropdown list for business logic if user doesn't select any value from dropdown list then i have to use default value of dropdown

Comment: Please show your code - at minimum, your html and what you've tried with jQuery :)

Comment: Have you tried already? Show us what you worked on. Also this is not angular or react just a JQuery. please remove the tags

Comment: Use the selected attribute with your options tag to get a default value displayed to the user. If the user changes the value in the dropdown list it will be reflected. Refer: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

Comment: It can be answered from the words used, and is answered.

Comment: _“if user doesn't select any value from dropdown list then i have to use default value of dropdown”_ - so, get the _value_ then … if the user did not actively make a choice, then the value _will be_ the default value … that’s what _default_ means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it by doing `document.getElementById('idoftheselect').value`

```js
function getDefaultVal() {

  console.log(document.getElementById('sel').value)

}
```

```html
<select id='sel'>
  <option val='1'>1</option>
  <option val='2'>2</option>
  <option val='3'>3</option>
  <option val='4'>4</option>
  <option val='5'>5</option>
</select>

<button type='button' onclick='getDefaultVal()'>Get Value</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

add one more option with selected attribut

```
<select id="someId">
 <option value="0" selected>Default</option>
</select>
```

using this

```
$('#selector option:selected').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case add one more option in dropdown like

```
<option value="-1">-select-</option>
```

then using jquery

```
$('select option:selected').val();
```

will always give the current dropdown selected value.